# Searching entire database with one word or more in java

Tags: java, c++, sql, swing, search

To prevent sql injections I am trying to avoid using `WHERE Surname LIKE '"search_txt.getText()"'` ... however using a `preparedStatement` is leaving the ? blank, in other words sql statement cannot execute even a correct search value is entered in the textfield...what is the problem in the line `pst1.setString(1, search_txt.getText()+"%");`

```
private void SearchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
             try{
             sql = "SELECT Title, Forename, Surname, Role FROM AcademicInfo WHERE Surname LIKE ? OR Forename LIKE ?";
            PreparedStatement pst1 = conn.prepareStatement(sql); 

            ResultSet rs2 = pst1.executeQuery();
            if (rs2.next()) {
                pst1.setString(1, search_txt.getText()+"%");
                pst1.setString(2, search_txt.getText()+"%");
                System.out.println(sql);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Found Academic");
                Update_table(sql);
            } else {
                System.out.println(sql);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Results Found");
            }
             }
            catch(Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }



        }
```

Comment: Welcome **SQL injection attacks**. Use prepared statements instead of messing with strings yourself!

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I am aware of that, this is just for an idea.

Comment: Other people may end up discovering this question by chance, and then think this is the proper way of doing it. It's best to avoid this kind of errors in every code snippet you post anywhere, so people don't see bad code without explanation of why it is bad and how to do better.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse edited but new problem

Answer (score 1):

This is a great use-case for a full-text search engine like [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this with MySQL is by using `FULLTEXT` search. It doesn't search, as you put it, the 'entire sql database,' but it can search a lot of columns.  This works pretty well.

The syntax is a little different from what you're used to.  This might do the trick for you.

```
SELECT Title, Forename, Surname, Role 
  FROM AcademicInfo 
 WHERE MATCH(Surname, Forename) AGAINST('searchterm' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I'll leave it to you to adapt that SQL statement to Java.

Here's the documentation.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: I used `IN BOOLEAN MODE` because FULLTEXT search works strangely with small data sets.  You may actually want natural-language search. Read the documentation.

Comment: java not liking the word AGAINST

Comment: `sql = "SELECT Title, Forename, Surname, Role FROM AcademicInfo WHERE MATCH(Forename, Surname, Role, Room, Email) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
        PreparedStatement pst1 = conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
       
        ResultSet rs2 = pst1.executeQuery();
        if (rs2.next()) {
         pst.setString(1, search_txt.getText());`

Comment: FULLTEXT supported in SQlite or not?

Comment: FULLTEXT is a MySQL feature, only.